# Implementing retry mechanism along circuit breaker in spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-retry, circuit-breaker

I want to implement retry mechanism along with circuit breaker in spring cloud gateway. Currently when I add Circuit Breaker filter alone to the spring cloud gateway, it works fine. And if I add Retry filter alone, it also works fine. But I want the request to be retried atleast 3 times automatically before the circuit changes to open state. Is there any way that I can integrate both retry and circuit breaker filter and make it work.

The flow of request will be:
User Request -> Spring Cloud Gateway -> Microservice

Sample spring cloud gateway configuration will be like:

application.yml

```
spring:
   cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: msOne
          uri: http://localhost:8081/
          predicates:
            - Path=/ms-one-services/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/ms-one-services(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: msOneServices
                fallbackUri: forward:/ms-one-services-fallback
            - name: Retry
              args:
                name: msOneServices
                retries: 3
                statuses: BAD_GATEWAY
                backoff:
                  firstBackOff: 5s
                  maxBackOff: 20s
                  factor: 2
                  basedOnPreviousValue: false
```